# How to deal with a lumpy, uneven floor for vinyl?

Tags: flooring

We're undertaking the renovation of a 100+ year old house which had some 'work' (bodge jobs!) done to it back in the seventies by the previous owners.
The whole kitchen-dining room floor slants slightly downwards towards the West and a section of the floorboards have been cut out to make way for a brick wall in the basement that sticks up a few mm above the floorboards. It's not load bearing, it looks like it's just there to make a room in the basement and that they couldn't be bothered to make the bricks smaller at the top.

We want to put medium sized vinyl tiles down in the kitchen (using vinyl tile adhesive).

The problems are that when we put plywood down it has a bit of a lump in the middle as it goes over the brick and if I try self levelling compound it's going to run down the slant.

I thought about trying to take the top layer of bricks out, but the brick wall is very close to the beam so access to it is really difficult.

Any suggestions would be very welcome!

Comment: Can either build up the floor on both sides of the brick with plywood, or cut the brick down to size with a masonry blade(messy, difficult).

Comment: Guessing the bricks are in a bad space and you can't build them up for an island/cupboard/room divider.

Comment: Alas, they're right in the middle of the floor so I can't build up an island/cupboard but building up with plywood could work! Cheers!

Comment: Have you considered leveling the floor? That may be an indication of other serious problems.

Answer (score 0):

grind the bricks down

You could maybe use a floor sander or use a masonry grinding wheel in a heavy duty angle grinder. There will be lots of dust, wear a dust mask, ear, and eye protection.